# Microsoft Azure speech to text behavior in JavaScript SDK in browser application

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech, microsoft-speech-platform

I have deployed Azure speech to text SDK in JavaScript SDK in browser application. Finding difficulties with the below scenarios.

1. When trying to start dictation in a text box which already has text in it, it always starts from the end of the text. I cannot start in the beginning or in between of existing text.
2. If the text box has data and when data is cleared and after I start the dictation, converted text as well the previously deleted text both appear. Dictated text is appended to the previously deleted text.
3. How do i disable auto punctuation? E.g. If I pause during dictation, the sentence ends with a period automatically. If I say how are you, it results in how are you?.

Expected results:

1. Based on my cursor placement in the text box, it should start the speech to text from that location.
2. Deleted text shouldn't re appear.
3. Want to disable auto punctuation and use dictation words like period, question mark, exclamation mark etc. in dictation.

Comment: Stackoverflow community appreciate if anyone can help in these issues.

Answer (score 0):

For question 3, if you [enabled dictation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechconfig?view=azure-node-latest#enableDictation__) previously, you many want to remove it from speech config to prevent interpretation of punctuations.